Resttemplate bean - headers of first rest call is getting cached for all further calls
I am using resttemplate as a bean to create a certificate based SSL connection
With below code I am able to achieve this but I am facing an issue where the header which I pass as part of first call gets cached for all rest calls.
I want to create rest template but header should not be cached as user in the header can be different in each call.
@Bean
    public RestTemplate(){
        File file =new File(path);
        SSLContextBuilder sslBuilder= SSLContexts.custom();
        sslBuilder= SSLBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(file, password,password);
        SSLContext sslcontext= SSLBuilder.build();
        SSLConnectionFactory factory= new SSLConnectionFactory(sslcontext, new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager=      PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(factory).build;
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient= HttpClients.custom(connectionManager).setConnectionManager().build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

        RestTemplate restTemplate= new RestTemplate(factory);
        return restTemplate;
    }

Do you have any pointers to overcome this?
I tried
headers.setExpire(0)
headers.setcache control 

didn't work
